# What do the Boost.Python ImportErrors mean?

Tags: python, c++, boost, importerror

Experimenting with Boost.Python, I stumbled across errors like this:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. python
>>> import Tackle
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./Tackle.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6Tackle12TGameSessionD1Ev
```

Now, what does that exactly mean? I know about `ImportError`, that's straight forward.
`Tackle.so` is the object file that failed to import, `undefined symbol` means that an expected symbol (constructor, variable, ...) is not defined, `Tackle` is the namespace and `TGameSession` is the class.

*But what do `_ZN6`, `12` and `D1Ev` mean?*

*Is there a documentation regarding these error-messages?*

---

After a bit of guessing, I found out that it's a copy-constructor in this case. But how should I know, apart from random guesses?

Comment: This is called name mangling: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling (see the complex example)

Comment: So that means that TGameSessionD1 is the copy-constructor of TGameSession. Interesting...

Comment: You can use `nm --demangle Tackle.so` to show a list of symbols that have been unmangled.

Comment: @iFreilicht FWIW, the constructor's name is probably just TGameSession as the name is already 12 characters long. D1 should be part of the type information, I would say this refers actually to the destructor, but this is not 100% sure, I find very few info on that. http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling-scope

Comment: Actually not a bad guess, I got `Tackle::TGameSession::~TGameSession()` from http://demangler.com/ :)

Comment: @Cilyan this is great! That site is very handy solving those linking-issues!

Comment: How did you solve this import problem?